# how to get data month wise from mysql if data is there are not

Tags: mysql

i have a table in that date wise data is there, how can i get data month wise even if the data is there are not.I tried but i can get only available data in database, but i need all months data, if data is not there. I tried with this query

```
select
    count(date) as absentdays,
    MONTHNAME(date) as monthname,
    MONTH(date) as monthnumber
from `tbl_records`
where FIND_IN_SET(2920,users_absent)
GROUP BY YEAR(date), MONTH(date)
```

[image]

i need data like this 
[image]

Comment: show us your expected result...

Comment: This is an example of where a helper table with a join will outperform anything. Unless performance doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `UNION` to do this;)

```
SELECT SUM(absentdays) AS absentdays, `MONTHNAME`, monthnumber
FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(DATE) AS absentdays, MONTHNAME(DATE) AS `MONTHNAME`, MONTH(DATE) AS monthnumber
    FROM `tbl_records`
    WHERE FIND_IN_SET(2920,users_absent)
    GROUP BY YEAR(DATE), MONTH(DATE)
    UNION SELECT 0 AS absentdays, 'January' AS MONTHNAME, 1 AS monthnumber
    UNION SELECT 0 AS absentdays, 'February' AS MONTHNAME, 2 AS monthnumber
    UNION SELECT 0 AS absentdays, 'March' AS MONTHNAME, 3 AS monthnumber
    UNION SELECT 0 AS absentdays, 'April' AS MONTHNAME, 4 AS monthnumber
    UNION SELECT 0 AS absentdays, 'May' AS MONTHNAME, 5 AS monthnumber
    UNION SELECT 0 AS absentdays, 'June' AS MONTHNAME, 6 AS monthnumber
    UNION SELECT 0 AS absentdays, 'July' AS MONTHNAME, 7 AS monthnumber
    UNION SELECT 0 AS absentdays, 'August' AS MONTHNAME, 8 AS monthnumber
    UNION SELECT 0 AS absentdays, 'September' AS MONTHNAME, 9 AS monthnumber
    UNION SELECT 0 AS absentdays, 'October' AS MONTHNAME, 10 AS monthnumber
    UNION SELECT 0 AS absentdays, 'November' AS MONTHNAME, 11 AS monthnumber
    UNION SELECT 0 AS absentdays, 'December' AS MONTHNAME, 12 AS monthnumber
) t
GROUP BY `MONTHNAME`, monthnumber
```